# How to store Jinja2 template output as a string

Tags: python

I want to use Jinja2 to store a template as a string variable in python instead of rendering it as a file. How would I go about doing this ?

For example using f-strings I'd do :

```
template = f""" This is a {foo}"""
```

Unfortunately f-strings don't suit my needs hence I wanted to try out Jinja2.

**Edit :**
Requirement

```
cars = {
  'tesla': {
    'cost': '34000',
    'length': '185',
    'range': '220',
  },
  'chevy': {
    'cost': '37000',
    'length': '134',
    'range': '238',
  }
```

I would like to take the values from this dictionary, insert it into template and store it as a string to be used later.

I tried using the below code but I get an invalid syntax error.

```
template1 = Template("""Tesla 
                        Cost : {{ cars.tesla.cost }}""")
template2 = template1.render()

# Expected Output
print(template2)
Tesla
Cost : 34000
```

Answer (score 4):

As its not clear what your requirement is, a simple way to store a jinja2 template in a variable is available through the `Template` class. The following example from the [jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/intro/#basic-api-usage) shows how you can do it:

```
from jinja2 import Template
template = Template('Hello {{ name }}!')
```

If I print `template`, it shows a `Template` object stored in memory:

```
print(template)
#Output
<Template memory:2ea4e10>
```

You can pass a custom name to the `render()` and print the template with the value of `name`:

```
print(template.render(name='John Wick'))
#Output:
Hello John Wick!
```

A slightly more complex template can be stored in a simple variable and then passed to `Template`:

```
jinja_string = """<title>{{title}}</title>
<ul>
{% for user in users %}
  <li>{{ user }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>"""

template = Template(jinja_string)
users = ["John", "Sam", "Joe"]
print(template.render(title="Users", users=users))

#Output:
<title>Users</title>
<ul>

  <li>John</li>

  <li>Sam</li>

  <li>Joe</li>

</ul>
```

For the expected output template:

```
jinja_string = """{{title}}:
{% for car,value in cars.items() %}  
  Car: {{ car }}
  Cost: {{value['cost']}}
  Length: {{value['length']}}
  Range: {{value['range']}}
{% endfor %}
"""

template = Template(jinja_string)

cars = {
  'tesla': {
    'cost': '34000',
    'length': '185',
    'range': '220',
  },
  'chevy': {
    'cost': '37000',
    'length': '134',
    'range': '238',
  }
}

print(template.render(title="Cars", cars=cars))
#Output:
Cars:

  Car: tesla
  Cost: 34000
  Length: 185
  Range: 220

  Car: chevy
  Cost: 37000
  Length: 134
  Range: 238
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited my question and added in some requirements.