# How to parse a django variable as Jinja2 syntax in the HTML file?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am currently working on a Django project and to generalize and simplify the amount of content in the HTML file, I have created a template tag that generates the syntax to be put into the HTML file.

If the original syntax was:

```
{% for i in results %}{{ i.a }},{{ i.b }},{{ i.c }}
{% endfor %}
```

the template tag generate_for_loop would create that syntax and output the above. Hence, I'd just have to replace the above for loop with

```
{% generate_for_loop "results" "a" "b" "c" %}
```

The template tag correctly generates the expected syntax, however I just have the for loop as a variable in the HTML file. If I wrap the generate_for_loop template tag inside `<h1>` tags and print it, I am seeing "{% for i in results %}{{ i.a }},{{ i.b }},{{ i.c }}
{% endfor %}", instead of the for loop getting evaluated.

My question is, what can I do to parse this string/variable again in the HTML file? Is there another alternate/better approach to achieve the functionality I'm trying to create here?

Edit: code for the generate_for_loop template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def generate_for_loop(*args):
    resulting_csv = ""
    '''
    Expected Run:
    {% generate_for_loop "results" "a" "b" "c" %}
    should result in
    {% for i in results %}{{ i.a }},{{ i.b }},{{ i.c }}
    {% endfor %}
    '''
    main_arg = args[0]
    values = args[1:]
    for_loop = "{% for i in "+main_arg+" %}"
    values_csv=""
    for v in values:
        values_csv+="{{ "i."+v+" }}, "
    values_csv=values_csv[:-2]
    resulting_csv=for_loop+values_csv+"{% endfor %}"
    return (resulting_csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code can simplify your code HTML, try change the template tag code generate_for_loop, like this example

```
@register.simple_tag
def generate_for_loop(object):
    list = [str(data) for key, data in object.items()]
    content = ",".join(list)
    return content
```

and call tag on template HTML like this with wrap h1

```
<h1> {% generate_for_loop results %} </h1>
```

Comment: That is what I have right now, but it prints "{% for i in results %}{{ i.a }},{{ i.b }},{{ i.c }}
{% endfor %}" instead of the contents of the for loop

Comment: Let's say I don't use the template tag and I just have the for loop in the HTML file, I get the all the values in results.a, results.b, results.c etc.. which is what I expect.

Comment: can you provide the template tag generate_for_loop code? because my result is like the loop in the HTML file

Comment: Just added the code, I don't think the template tag is the problem, the main issue is parsing the string as Jinja2 syntax instead of just a string in the HTML file.

Comment: no, you can't execute syntax jinja from the returned template tag, because the template tag is just returned value only, not will be executed from string, int, boolean, etc to jinja template, except if you use jinja Template like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54446438/how-to-store-jinja2-template-output-as-a-string and this https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#jinja2.Template